# xamarin cross platform form for buttons with image and text layout

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am looking to create a xamarin cross platform dashboard page with some buttons. Each button have an icon image and a text. I tried two approaches 1. with using inbuilt property of Icon of Button control and another with separate StackLayout

But my output needs some optimization on xaml 
[image]

The xaml i tried is like this

```
    <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition  Height="150" ></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="150"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
           <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#3094d2"  >
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Image   Source="@drawable/announcement.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                     <Button Text="Announcement"   TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

            <Button Text="News &amp; Events"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  BackgroundColor="#287cbe" Image="@drawable/announcement.png" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_NewsHome_Clicked"  />
            <Button Text="Messages" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  BackgroundColor="#5153a9" Image="@drawable/announcement.png" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_SMSHome_Clicked" />



            <Button Text="SMS Alers" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Image="@drawable/announcement.png" BackgroundColor="#a434a6" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_SMSHome_Clicked" />

    </Grid>
```

What adjustments i have to do on Vertical and Horizontal align to make my ouput looks like that on the left side

Comment: Try RelativeLayout in the PCL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XLabs Extended Button](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageButton) to get desired output